# How to Turn off GIT Credentials Manager

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

When GIT is installed it asks if you want to use the Credentials Manager.

Is there a way to turn off the credentials manager through the settings or command line after it has been installed with the credentials manager turned on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+disable+credential+manager

Answer (score 2):

For Windows try this:

`git config credential.modalprompt false --global`

You can disable SSH private key auth too:

`git config --edit --global`

and set `askpass` value to empty string:

```
[core]
    askpass =
```